# What user profile the system uses when runs a service in windows

Tags: windows

All,

I have no idea how Windows service works, just curious when we register a windows service(such as auto run a server after reboot), if it requires a user profile to load info(such as pulling data from somewhere else), what user profile does it load?

Thanks,

Comment: I would assume `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge Thanks, could you tell how can I check what that is after I restart the windows? The senario is I have a Tomcat running JAVA app, that app needs windows user credential to request initial data, I want to know whic user name and password it uses

Comment: The service loads from whatever account it is configured to run under, which by default is SYSTEM (which has no user profile and very limited rights such as no network access). If you need it to load specific information, create a new user account and profile for that service, and have the service run using that account by configuring it to do so.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, so say my user name is kuan, then when I register a service, the profile load will be kuan?

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, get it.

Comment: @KenWhite, the SYSTEM logon uses the default profile, i.e. "HKU\.DEFAULT", which is stored in the registry hive "%SystemRoot%\System32\config\DEFAULT". Its profile directory (i.e. %UserProfile%) is "%SystemRoot%\System32\config\systemprofile". Its user name (i.e. %UserName%) is special cased as the machine name. Also, the SYSTEM account is anything but limited. It's the most powerful in terms of privileges and access to everything, including the network. That's why the "LOCAL SERVICE" (no network access) and "NETWORK SERVICE" accounts exist, for services that don't need unlimited access.

Comment: @eryksun other than those slightly diff, do you agree what Ken told me in general? Like SYSTEM

Comment: Most services run as SYSTEM, LOCAL SERVICE, or NETWORK SERVICE. The latter two have their own profiles, respectively HKU\S-1-5-19 and HKU\S-1-5-20, and their own profile directories under "%SystemRoot%\ServiceProfiles". One reason to create an account for a service is to secure access to objects and files, but since Vista services can be configured to have a unique service ID in the process access token, which can be used to secure objects without requiring a new account.

Comment: @eryksun: Ok. :-) I stand corrected.

Comment: Typically services will work on behalf of (i.e. impersonate) a client. For example, if communicating with a client over a named pipe, a service can call `ImpersonateNamedPipeClient`. Then access that user's registry profile via `RegOpenCurrentUser` or `RegOpenUserClassesRoot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select what user run each service registered and the system comes with users assigned per service.  The most used by the system is SYSTEM.

To check this you have to:

- Go to services.
- Right click on the desired service and properties.
- Go to the Log on tab and check.

If the Local System account is selected the username is SYSTEM which has special permissions on almost all folder and Windows sections including users' profiles data.

By the other hand if you would like to do something special with an specific account you can tell the system the service will start with the account specified.  Just make sure to update the password information every time the user change it.

Regards,

Luis

Comment: I think your signature should probably be moved to the profile

Comment: Thanks for this guide.